# react semantic dropdown not working on Enter key

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

When I type in values and enter I am getting values in input but code is not generating values.

```
      <label>Country</label> 
                    <Dropdown
                      placeholder={`${enteredCountry}`} 
                      search selection
                       options={countryOptions}
                       defaultValue={enteredCountry} 
                       onChange =
                      {searchHandler 
                      }
                      
                       
                       />
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a fix like this...

```
 const searchHandler = (e,data) =>{    
              setEnteredCountry(e.target.textContent);
              console.log('text value ',e.target.textContent) 
              if(e.code === 'Enter'){
                console.log('data.....',data);
                  data.options.forEach(element => {
                      element.value === data.value && setEnteredCountry(element.text)
                  });   
              }   
      }
```